# Comments on 9gag don't get any notifications on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments

Previously, I used to be notified on my Facebook whenever my comment on 9gag got any sort of response (likes or comments). But now its been a month and I am having this problem. I don't get notified anymore. In fact, whenever I login to Facebook, some of my notifications disappear before I can click them. Like they are there when I login and then they just disappear when the page finishes loading. And I'm pretty sure those notifications are the ones coming from 9gag.

So far I have tried:

1. Using another browser
2. Deleting history , cookies
3. Rechecked the settings of 9gag app on Facebook , and it's not blocked
   at all
4. Tried another friends account and got the same problem

So now I have no way to keep track of my activity on the site. Any help would be appreciated.